# '80s sci-fi novel about about an astronaut returning to Earth to find it devoid of human life

Tags: story-identification, novel, astronauts

I read this as hardcover from the library back in the 80's.

The story involves an astronaut who returns to Earth from a long mission (50 years, 100?) and discovers everyone is missing.  The only computer system that he can access is a low-level system named HOMER.

Homer proceeds to tell the story of what happened, that there was some sort of technology movement that overtook the world that led to all conscious beings transmigrating to a higher plane.

Turns out the astronaut was to be their fail-safe to bring them back. Once the story is told, Homer is able to trigger their return.

Things I remember:

- Cover showed an overgrown city street
- The techno revolutionaries had undergone genetic mods of some sort and were living in Antarctica.
- There was an anti-revolutionary song that was a modified from a kids' song.  I remember a verse as being

  > The Ants come marching two by two, aroo, aroo
  >
  > The Ants come marching two by two, aroo, aroo
  >
  > Forth to the North to steal our warmth and they all go marching back to the pole again

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe this is *[Portal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1315984.Portal)* by Rob Swigart, originally published as an [interactive novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(interactive_novel)) in 1986, and then as a hardcover novel in 1988.

[image]

The synopsis for the interactive novel mentions the astronaut returning to Earth after a 100-year voyage, to find it devoid of all human life, and using a computer terminal containing a storytelling mainframe named Homer to find out what happened:

> The player, taking on the role of the unnamed astronaut protagonist, returns from a failed 100-year voyage to 61 Cygni to find the Earth devoid of humans. Cars are rusted and covered with moss, the streets are completely barren, and everything appears as though the entire human race had just vanished suddenly. The player happens upon a barely functioning computer terminal that is tied into a storytelling mainframe, Homer. Through this interface, the player, assisted by Homer who attempts to weave the information into a coherent narrative, discovers information in order to piece together the occurrences leading to the disappearance of the human race. For instance, spending some time in the Medical Records section may unlock a piece of data in the Science section, and through these links the player can finish the game.

> A hardcover novel, titled Portal: A Dataspace Retrieval (1988) and composed mostly of the text from the interactive novel with some new additions, was written by the same author, Rob Swigart, and first published by St. Martin's Press. It takes the form of a series of notes on different subjects, in an order the player would encounter them through Homer. A softcover edition was released by Backinprint.com in 2001.

This is the song verse you recited in full:

> The ants are coming one by one, Aroo, aroo.
>
> The ants are coming one by one, Aroo, aroo.
>
> The ants are coming one by one.
>
> Forth to the North to steal some sun
>
> And they'll all go crawling back to the Pole again.

And you can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Portal/26vOeLjyKscC?hl=en&gbpv=0).